# Linux shave last 5 characters from filenames

Tags: linux

So I have a bunch of different files in a directory and I want shave the last 5 characters off each filename.

For example I have files in the directory named

```
README.md?dl=1
mod.cpp?dl=1
CHANGELOG_RU.txt?dl=1
```

And they need to be named instead

```
README.md
mod.cpp
CHANGELOG_RU.txt
```

So is there a Linux command I could run that would do this to all files and files in sub directories within a folder?

Comment: `mmv *?dl=1 '#1'` I think should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash` built-ins:

```
$ ls
README.md?dl=1  mod.cpp?dl=1
$ for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file:0:((${#file}-5))}"; done
$ ls
README.md   mod.cpp
```

Enable `globstar` to trigger recursive behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
shopt -s globstar
rename 's/.....$//' **
```

Note that you will need `bash` version 4 or higher to use `globstar`.

Ubuntu 10 and Fedora 12 or later should include Bash 4 or higher.

Comment: Whether this works or not will depend on the distro; not everyone uses the same version of rename.